# add action / url

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress 3.2.2

What's the steps to define a custom link in the wordpress admin such as

```
http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/admin.php?action=update_posts
```

so that when this link is accessible by admins, a specific function is executed.

(in the context of a custom wordpress plugin)

**EXAMPLE CODE**

```
function my_special_function(){

    echo '<div> Hello World </div>';

}

$page_title = "Hello Page Title";
$menu_title = "Hello Menu Title";
$capability = "import";
$menu_slug = "My Menu Slug";
$function = my_special_function;
add_menu_page($page_title,  $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function);
```

So I have this example code. Now what?  And what url should I load to see hello world printed on in the html page?

Comment: That's usually done with `add_menu_page`. The second example on the documentation page covers what it sounds like you're trying to do? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page

Comment: looks correct. is there a specific file I have to write this function in?

Comment: You will need to "hook" it from a plugin or theme file. In your case, the `admin_menu` hook should be fine.

Comment: Updated example code. can you elaborate on `admin_menu` in the context of the example code?

Comment: Sure. Let me get you a full-er answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to use [`add_menu_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page). That involves two steps. First, you will need to define a function (`my_menu_page` in the example below) to create the menu.

```
// inside plugin file
function my_menu_page ()
{
  $page_title = "Hello Page Title";
  $menu_title = "Hello Menu Title";
  $capability = "import";
  $menu_slug = "My Menu Slug";
  $function = my_special_function;

  add_menu_page($page_title,  $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function);
}
```

Once you've got that, you will need to register it with WP using the [`add_action`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) function and a hook. For an admin menu, the `admin_menu` hook is probably appropriate.

```
// inside plugin file
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_menu_page');
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Almost. Just one question.

What am I getting `You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.` when I am specifying `$capability = "import"` and my user accessing this new admin page/url is an Administrator?

Comment: Hmm, not sure. How about trying with `"administrator"` or `"manage_options"` instead?